# Adding form data to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm totally new to coding. I'm trying to save data to firebase database with the hierarchy : Job ID (job 1, job2,etc) -> job parameters (date, priority etc)

This is the form I am using :

[image: submission form]

This is my firebase hierarchy from my original code

[image: firebase structure]

This is my code:

```
package com.example.myname.todo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class JobForm extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_form);

    // Connect to the Firebase database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // Add items via the Button and EditText at the bottom of the window.
    final EditText jobNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.job_id);
    final EditText jobDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_now);
    final EditText jobPri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.job_imp);
    final EditText jobDeet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.job_dis);
    final EditText jobMch1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_machine);
    final EditText jobMch2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second_machine);
    // Get a reference to the child items it the database


    final DatabaseReference jobID = database.getReference("Job_ID");
    final DatabaseReference dateStart = database.getReference("Start_Date");
    final DatabaseReference jobImp = database.getReference("Job_Priority");
    final DatabaseReference jobDes = database.getReference("Job_Description");
    final DatabaseReference jobMach1 = database.getReference("First_Machine");
    final DatabaseReference jobMach2 = database.getReference("Second_Machine");



    final Button but_sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_sub);

    but_sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create a new child with a auto-generated ID.
            DatabaseReference childRef = jobID.push();
            // Set the child's data to the value passed in from the text box.
            childRef.setValue(jobNum.getText().toString());
            DatabaseReference childRef2 = dateStart.push();
            childRef2.setValue(jobDate.getText().toString());
            DatabaseReference childRef3 = jobImp.push();
            childRef3.setValue(jobPri.getText().toString());
            DatabaseReference childRef4 = jobDes.push();
            childRef4.setValue(jobDeet.getText().toString());
            DatabaseReference childRef5 = jobMach1.push();
            childRef5.setValue(jobMch1.getText().toString());
            DatabaseReference childRef6 = jobMach2.push();
            childRef6.setValue(jobMch2.getText().toString());
        }
    });


}
```

}

I would like to know what to do so that each job entered by the user creates a Child in the database, with its specific information. so like:

- Job1 (job 1 info, when expanded)
- job2 (job 2 info when expanded)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seemed to me that you messed up while learning firebase or how Firebase works, you don't need to declare DatabaseReference everytime, you only have to call it once for a table. See this:

```
final EditText jobNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.job_id);
final EditText jobDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_now);
final EditText jobPri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.job_imp);
final EditText jobDeet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.job_dis);
final EditText jobMch1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_machine);
final EditText jobMch2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second_machine);
// Get a reference to the child items it the database


final DatabaseReference job = database.getReference("JOBS");
final Button but_sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_sub);\`but_sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // you must creat a job class 
       // asumming you did it will have the toString()method in ever parmeteter in the constracter 
       Job job = new Job(jobNum.getText().toString(),...exc);
       job.child(jobNum).setValue(job);
```

// Now you will should have in your Firebase database a Node called job and it key is the jobNum and the value is job .

```
    }
});


  }`
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will update you with the results when i get the chance to implement the changes

Comment: it worked perfectly thank you for your help! . ps if i wanted to add more nodes, would i just need to create another class?

Comment: great to hear that it worked, if you need to create other nodes for the same class, just use the `DatabaseReference job', if it was for a different class just defined a new `DatabaseReference '